# Add the URL scheme during application start up

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm developing an iphone application. I know how to add the URL scheme in plist. But I want to add the URL scheme during application start up in code. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think so. BTW, it's called a **scheme**, not a __theme__.

Comment: Thanks @jcaron, I corrected the typo. :)